# Define position for SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I create the `SCNBox` based on the `SCNVector3`. But I don't understand the concept of the creation.

For 2D rectangle, the *x* and *y* represent the rectangle top right corner.
For ARKit 3D `SCNBox`, what is the *x, y* and *z* represent for? Is that represent the center of the `SCNBox`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're setting position of your `SCNNode`, you're initializating `SCNVector3` which describing node's position.

You have to define position of node's **center point** in relation to the position of the parent (*center point* is not necessarily in the center of your custom node, but if you have basic nodes with geometry like `SCNBox` or `SCNSphere`, *center point* is in the center)

A simple example can be adding node with geometry `SCNBox` to `rootNode` of `sceneView`'s `scene` which you get when you in Xcode create new *Augmented Reality App*.

```
let cube = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
let material = SCNMaterial()
material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
cube.materials = [material]
let node = SCNNode()
node.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -0.5)
node.geometry = cube
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

[image]

As you can see, to initialize `SCNVector3` you have to define *x, y* and *z* positions of node's *center point*. Note that units are in meters.

I created (very nice) picture with *x,y* and *z* axises which should help you to understand how to position your `SCNNode`:

...origin is origin of the node's parent's coordinate system when node is added. Image origin of **AR world** simplified as position of the center of `ARSCNView`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. One more question. If I obtain the camera position from ARFrame, is the x, y and z value also represent the center point of the iPhone?